# Makefile: How to run certain prereq recipe depending on target?

Tags: c, makefile, compilation, gnu-make

```
OBJLIST1=foo.o bar.o baz.o
    
target1: $(OBJLIST1)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@

$(OBJLIST1) : $(OBJLIST1:%.o=%.c)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@

target1-i: $(OBJLIST1)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@

$(OBJLIST1) : $(OBJLIST1:%.o=%.c)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DSOME_MACRO -c $^ -o $@
```

I need to be able to compile list of object files differently depending on the target i call. I have no idea how to do that tbh, this is giving me a bunch of errors like "overriding recipe for target...", "ignoring old recipe for target...". How can i specify which recipe i want to call in a target command? Apparently the order doesn't change much.

Comment: give your targets different names and pass the target name as an argument to make . Ex : ```make debug_build``` , ```make prod_build```. Is that what you would like to do?

Comment: You cannot have alternative recipes for the same target in one makefile.  There are various ways that you could use variables to influence the details of your recipes, however, and it looks like you might find a solution for what you're after along that route.  You might also consider using a system such as CMake or the Autotools to build your build system, as these know how to deal with this kind of thing.

Comment: @Ait-GacemNabil No, they already have different names, first one has target1, second one is target1-i, but even if i type make target1, or make target1-i, it gives me an error, so this doesn't work apparently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [target specific variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html) to set relevant variables.

The example below shows how to add EXTRA_FLAGS to the `target1-i` target.

```
OBJLIST1=foo.o bar.o baz.o

target1: $(OBJLIST1)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@

target1-i: EXTRA_FLAGS=-DSOME_MACRO
target1-i: $(OBJLIST1)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@

$(OBJLIST1) : $(OBJLIST1:%.o=%.c)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_FLAGS) -c $^ -o $@
```

Comment: This is OK if you want to build just one of the targets from scratch. Try: `make -n target1 target1-i`. Even worse, what if the object files have already been made (with what flags?).

Comment: @nickie Very true. A fully fledged makefile for that case would use different build trees for different targets. At least that's one way I've done it.

Comment: Another alternative is to name the object files differently, for instance by appending the name of the main target.  Automake will do this for you when multiple targets depend on some of the same sources.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to have the same object file built in two different ways. This is ambiguous (see my comment in @kaylum's answer). I would try something like:

```
SOURCES=foo.c bar.c baz.c

%_1.o : %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@

%_2.o : %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DSOME_MACRO -c $^ -o $@

target1: $(SOURCES:%.c=%_1.o)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@

target2: $(SOURCES:%.c=%_2.o)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@
```

which gives you:

```
$ make -n target1
cc  -c foo.c -o foo_1.o
cc  -c bar.c -o bar_1.o
cc  -c baz.c -o baz_1.o
cc  -c foo_1.o bar_1.o baz_1.o -o target1

$ make -n target2
cc  -DSOME_MACRO -c foo.c -o foo_2.o
cc  -DSOME_MACRO -c bar.c -o bar_2.o
cc  -DSOME_MACRO -c baz.c -o baz_2.o
cc  -c foo_2.o bar_2.o baz_2.o -o target2
```